# MSBuild Publishing Database with Profile fails with "Unable to connect to server"

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a VS 2013 and TFS 2013 project that has a database (sqlproj). I have setup a publishing profile for the database in my solution and entered the username and password into the credentials, and checked the box to save the password. The database publishes successfully from my computer, but when I check it in the build fails with a "Unable to connect to server" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one of the commenters on [this post](http://blog.danskingdom.com/using-msbuild-to-publish-a-vs-2012-ssdt-sqlproj-database-project-the-same-way-as-a-vs-2010-dbproj-database-project/) was having the same problem I was, except in reverse. I changed my publish profile to use integrated security, which does not work for me locally, but did work on my build server.